# How to mimic Alt key functionality from ubuntu gnome to OSX iTerm2?

Tags: macos, iterm2

When I use Vim on my home Ubuntu computer, I am able to use alt-[key] as a quick way to jump from insert mode to normal mode and immediately run the [key] command. One thing I frequently do is: alt-j or alt-k from insert mode, where it immediately jumps up or down in normal mode. Unfortunately on mac iterm2, using alt-j does nothing and option-j likewise simply adds the ' character. How can I edit this to use option/alt in the same way?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I suspect this is a « feature » of iterm2 (normally the alt keys send escape and then a key code). I expect answers will tell you to toggle a pref in iterm2

Comment: This is an iTerm configuration issue. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/196357/9447571) about handling of the Meta key, you probably want `ESC+`.